# How to edit a published post?

Tags: plugins, database

I'm writing a plugin. Can anyone please show me how to edit the content of a published post? I've tried using this:

```
function edit( $post_ID ) {
$content = "Hello. This is a test.";
$post_info = get_post($post_ID);    
$post_info->post_content = "$content";
}

add_action('publish_post', 'edit');
```

Although I'm having no luck. Can anyone suggest how to get it working? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained why you doing this, ie. what's the end goal here? Are you trying to pull a particular post, modify a property then save that change? More details about what you're trying to accomplish would be most helpful for anyone reading..

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've made a plugin which gets the contents of a post and then replaces various words, etc. and then sends it to an email address. That's all fine and works great. It's just I want the changes to be saved to the actual post as well. :)

Comment: Ok, but at what point do you need to make this change, when you load a particular plugin page, when you click link on a given page, or when a post is saved? When should this occur and is intended as an automated action, or one you perform by clicking something? Based on what you've said i believe Scribu has already given you the info you need(which is why i think there may be more to it than your question is detailing).

Comment: I want the change to be done after it's been published/created. I've been using "publish_post" which changes it after the post has been published. That works and it changes the content, but it just enters a loop because changing the content causes it to be published again.

Comment: Try the `wp_insert_post_data` hook.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You modified a copy of a row from the wp_posts table.

You need to send the modified version back to the database:

`wp_update_post( $post_info );`

Comment: Thanks, although it's making the plugin time out. It seems to edit the database though, but just times out while doing it.

Comment: Ah, right. It's because it enters an endless loop. Try replacing the 'publish_post' hook with something else, like 'transition_post_status'.

Comment: Nope. No luck. Does the same thing although it doesn't actually edit the post when using 'transition_post_status'. Anything else I can try? :) Thanks again.

Comment: Woops. I've got a "Internal Server Error" when going to post-new.php now. :L

Comment: Are you sure you need to store the changes in the database? Wouldn't it be better if you did it before it's displayed? You can do this via 'the_content' filter.

Comment: Hm, na that doesn't work. It'll need to be stored in the database. Is there no way for this to work then? No way to stop it entering an endless loop? :(